excel file not calculating using the formula
I am using Import-Excel to calculate some data using excel formula.
Below is the code
# Import the ImportExcel module
Import-Module ImportExcel

# Define the path to the existing Excel file
$excelFilePath = "E:\VLANReports\20240702_VLAN_Data.xlsx"

# Import ImportExcel Module
Import-Module ImportExcel

# Define the path to the new Excel file
$newExcelFilePath = "E:\VLAN.xlsx"

# Read the data from the "USER" sheet
Write-Output "Reading USER data from the new file..."
$userData = Import-Excel -Path $newExcelFilePath -WorksheetName "USER"

# Check if user data was imported
if ($userData -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "No data found in USER sheet. Exiting script."
    exit
}

# Create a new worksheet "Sheet1" and copy data from "USER"
Write-Output "Exporting USER data to Sheet1..."
$userData | Export-Excel -Path $newExcelFilePath -WorksheetName "Sheet1" -ClearSheet -AutoSize -TableName "UserData"

# Open the Excel package
Write-Output "Opening Excel package..."
$excelPackage = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $newExcelFilePath

# Get the worksheet
$sheet1 = $excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"]

if ($sheet1 -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "Sheet1 not found. Exiting script."
    exit
}

# Define the headers to be added starting from column N
$headers = @(
    "Bckp`nSG VLanID",
    "Bckp`nnetwork label",
    "Bckp`nSubnet",
    "Bckp`nNetmask",
    "Bckp`nGateway",
    "Bckp`nNetwork"
)

# Add headers manually to "Sheet1"
Write-Output "Adding headers to Sheet1..."
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $headers.Length; $i++) {
    $columnIndex = 14 + $i
    $headerCell = $sheet1.Cells[1, $columnIndex]
    $headerCell.Value = $headers[$i]
    $headerCell.Style.WrapText = $true
}

# Define the formulas for columns N, O, P, Q, R, S
$formulas = [ordered]@{
    N = '=IFERROR(IFS(MID(C2,1,1)="2",XLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(MID(C2,2,3)),BACKUP!$C:$C,BACKUP!$C:$C),MID(C2,1,1)="3",XLOOKUP(C2+300,BACKUP!$C:$C,BACKUP!$C:$C)),"")'
    O = '=IF(N2<>"",XLOOKUP(N2,BACKUP!$C:$C,BACKUP!$B:$B),"")'
    P = '=IF(N2<>"",LEFT(S2,SEARCH("/",S2,1)-1),"")'
    Q = '=IF(S2<>"", LEFT(S2, FIND("/", S2)-1) & " (" & TEXTJOIN(".", TRUE, MID(S2, FIND("/", S2), LEN(S2))) & ")", "")'
    R = '=IF(N2<>"",XLOOKUP(N2,BACKUP!$C:$C,BACKUP!$G:$G),"")'
    S = '=IF(N2<>"",XLOOKUP(N2,BACKUP!$C:$C,BACKUP!$A:$A),"")'
}

# Get the last row in the sheet
$lastRow = $sheet1.Dimension.End.Row
Write-Output "Last row in Sheet1: $lastRow"

# Add formulas to "Sheet1"
Write-Output "Adding formulas to Sheet1..."
$formulas.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $column = $_
    $colIndex = [array]::IndexOf($formulas.Keys, $column) + 14
    for ($row = 2; $row -le $lastRow; $row++) {
        $cell = $sheet1.Cells[$row, $colIndex]
        $cell.Formula = $formulas[$column] -replace '2', $row
    }
}

# Force recalculation of all formulas in the workbook
Write-Output "Forcing recalculation of all formulas..."
$sheet1.Calculate()

# Save and close the Excel package
Write-Output "Saving the Excel package..."
Close-ExcelPackage $excelPackage

Write-Output "Sheet 'Sheet1' has been created with the 'USER' data, headers added, and formulas applied."

The problem is in the cells (column N onwards), I am able to see only the formula being displayed not the calculated data.

Please let me know what is wrong with the code.

As aside, why do you Import-Module ImportExcel twice? Also it looks like your code is trying to get user data from a new file that has not been created yet..

Many possible reasons for this - e.g.

format - white font colour (baseuse your screensnot?
suspect the cells hae 'text' format (why in your screenshot does function appear in formula bar but not in cell which appears to have a value right-aligned albeit beyond the right crop you applied ? hmm



Option 1 : potential quick fix:

Try adding this to the for loop:
Write-Output "Adding formulas to Sheet1..."
$formulas.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $column = $_
    ....
    ....
    $cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "General"
    $cell.Formula = $cell.Formula
    }
}



Option 2 : approach

If still not coming right - this approach adds vb module, applies functions, then removes the module (refine/tailor to your case as req.):
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# Set isF = 0/1 for value/function respectively
$code_0 = @"
Sub SC(cellRef As String, formula As String, isF As Integer)
    If isF = 1 Then
        Range(cellRef).Formula2R1C1 = formula
    Else
        Range(cellRef).Value = formula
    End If
End Sub
"@

$code_1 = @"
Sub Macro0()
    SC "A1", "A", 0
    SC "B1", "B", 0
    SC "C1", "C", 0
    SC "A2", "=SEQUENCE(10)", 1
    SC "B2", "=SEQUENCE(10,,-20)", 1
    SC "C2", "=SUMX2MY2(RC[-2]#,RC[-1]#)", 1
End Sub
"@

$code_2 = @"
Sub RemoveMacro()
    Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Remove Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Module1")
End Sub
"@

# Add VBA code, run Macro0
$vbComponent = $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1) # 1 = vbext_ct_StdModule
$vbComponent.Name = "Module1"
$vbComponent.CodeModule.AddFromString($code_0)
$vbComponent.CodeModule.AddFromString($code_1)
$vbComponent.CodeModule.AddFromString($code_2)

# Run the macro
$excel.Run("Macro0")

# Remove the macro module after execution
$excel.Run("RemoveMacro")

Write-Output "voila!"
Pause



I simply create new workbook to illustrate/proof of concept:
caveats: option 1 - I had to ask GPT how to simulate an 'F2', 'enter' keystroke because that's the only way you can evaluate function that Excel thinks is text, after changing format to General or something.
option 2 - GPT assisted some time ago with the SC function on a completely different problem, relating to xlwings / python where I created vb code there - I've since refined and used in many projects - see it as my own. Both options were tested/succeeded using the simplified example with screenshot below - i.e. the cell.function = cell.function worked in the same exercise set up for option 2 if that makes sense !
we're living in a new world - embrace/leverage it already! ☺

